# Call C# function of parent application inside a plugin interface

Tags: c#, plugins, interface

I've created a simple program that loads all the DLL's in a "Plugins" directory as plugins to my application. I have a nice form with a listview of all the available plugins, and even buttons that get dynamically loaded to call functions inside the plugins.

My question is as follows: How can I call a function from inside the plugin to modify something in the parent application?

For instance:
I've got a TextBox that i'm appending text to, we'll call this ConsoleLog. This is inside the parent application on a Form. I have a function called Log.WriteLine that appends text to the ConsoleLog TextBox.

I'd like to be able to expose the parent applications Log.WriteLine function to the plugins that are added at runtime. Is this possible?

So in the plugin interface DLL I'd be able to do

```
Log.WriteLine("Hello Plugin!");
```

and it should show up in the parent application's TextBox.

Thanks

Comment: Well do your plugins conform to some sort of interface? If so, you could initialize them, passing in an appropriate logging implementation.

Comment: The plugin interface is a separate dll to the parent project called projectlib, inside that it defines string titles, description, and a LoadPlugin void. I can't access the parent application from that lib because it would cause a circular reference.

Comment: No, but plugin library could define a logging *interface* which the parent application implements, and the plugin initialization process could include providing the plugin with that interface...

Comment: As @JonSkeet says, create a an assembly with the interface, plus other interfaces that can be implemented by your container, but called by your plugin. (no implementation) . This article seems pretty reasonable for what you have said https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972962.aspx

Comment: Take a look at MEF https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx maybe it will give you some design ideas.